# Backgroundworker for wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, task, dispatcher, continuation

I need to execute two methods simultaneously, only after completion of this next thing should continue, the problem i have a UI which throws me error if use task (Its a WPF appliation).

```
Task Data= Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Readdetails());
Task Data2= Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadProcedure());

Data.Wait();
Data2.Wait();
```

but i am getting Error(must-create-dependencysource-on-same-thread-as-dependencyobject).

something like this i need.

```
private void ReadProcedure()
        {
            this.Pro = //some stuff;
        }

private void ReadProcedure2()
        {
            this.Pro2 = //some stuff;
        }

if(this.pro!=null && this.pro2!=null)
{
//other things to carry out.
}
```

I tried using Dispacter but it seems it's still not working.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To wait for multiple task, you can your [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Task.WaitAll(Data,Data2);
```

To update on UI, you can use [synchronizationcontext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Task UITask= Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
     if(this.pro!=null && this.pro2!=null)
     {
      //other things to carry out.
     }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

You can combine above two, using [TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990851(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Add more details to your question, including code snippet to be executed on UI, and background thread.